# Branch difference in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to show the branch differences of the GitLab. So I used https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits

I did not understand how it is comparing the branches.

`GET /projects/:id/repository/compare?from=master&to=feature`
in the above, what compares between master and feature?

Does this compare differences in terms of commits that are not available in master?
Or shows different commits which are not available in each other?

As I observed it is showing the only differences that are not present in main.

If yes, how can I show the differences between both branches in using a single API?

Comment: Doesnt the diff alrready show u this ?

Comment: Say there are 2 branches, A and B. B is forked from some commit on A. As I know, when comparing A and B, Gitlab cares about the changes which have been applied on B since the fork point. By commits, it's the result of `git log A..B` (two dots). By diffs, it's the result of `git diff A...B` (three dots). It focuses on the workload on the forked branch (usually a developing branch). Suppose the A log is `O1-O2-O3` and the B log is `O1-O2-O4-O5`. `git log A..B` returns `O4` and `O5`. `git diff A...B` returns the diff between `O2` and `O5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this compare differences in terms of commits that are not available in master? or shows different commits which are not available in each other?

Your API call is missing the `straight` argument:

> `straight` boolean: Comparison method.
>
> - `true` for direct comparison between from and to (`from..to`),
> - `false` to compare using merge base (`from...to`).
>
> Default is `false`.

In your case, `&straight=true` would show you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @VonC for help in understanding how it does works... but in that case, the API is not giving me any information about what branch the commit came from?... is that from 'form_branch' or from 'to_branch' ... by using the web_url only I can figure it out. Is that possible to know on what branch the commit is from when I enable `&straight=true`

Comment: @ganeshtirumani True, you have to consider `from_branch` and `to_branch` to understand where the 2 commits being compared come from.